# Obtaining formatted strings from a text_file_backend

Tags: c++, logging, boost, boost-log

I'm using *boost-log* in my application. I want to both write logs to file and to send the logged *strings* over the network (for replication purposes).

For *file-logging*, I'm using a `text_file_backend` (together with a `synchronous_sink<text_file_backend>`); this works good, and logs to file information with a **certain format**. I want to obtain **the same formatted string**, to be able to send it over the network.

How can I squeeze out from the `text_file_backend` the actual string that it will write down to file?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add [multiple stream](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/sink_backends.html) to the `backend`:

```
void init_logging()
{
    boost::shared_ptr< logging::core > core = logging::core::get();

    // Create a backend and attach a couple of streams to it
    boost::shared_ptr< sinks::text_ostream_backend > backend =
        boost::make_shared< sinks::text_ostream_backend >();
    backend->add_stream(
        boost::shared_ptr< std::ostream >(&std::clog, boost::null_deleter()));
    backend->add_stream(
        boost::shared_ptr< std::ostream >(new std::ofstream("sample.log")));

    /*** Add your network stream here ***/

    typedef sinks::synchronous_sink< sinks::text_ostream_backend > sink_t;
    boost::shared_ptr< sink_t > sink(new sink_t(backend));
    core->add_sink(sink);
}
```

### Update

Stick to [`text_file_backend`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/log/doc/html/boost/log/sinks/text_file_backend.html), you can use the `void set_close_handler(close_handler_type const & handler)` to set a callback function which reads the closed log file and send it to your log server.

If you cannot stand with the delay, then use `set_open_handler`, and start a new thread to read the file.

Ultimately, you can subclass `text_file_backend` and overload the `consume` method which I think the fontend calls. Refer to [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/extension.html#log.extension.sinks.minimalistic_sink_backend) page for the backend API

Comment: It's the first thing I've thought, too. But it seems that the `text_file_backend` does not provide an `add_stream` feature.

Comment: Don't use `text_file_backend`, use `text_ostream_backend` instead. Or do you need the file separation (rotation) function of  `text_file_backend`?

Comment: Yes, I need file rotation because the application is supposed to run for an indefinitely long period of time. I've solved adding a `text_ostream_backend`, but I can't believe that there is no way to avoid this *duplication*...